# Elasticsearch return field of object

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following json object

```
{ "type_name" : 
    {
        "id" : "string"
        "timestamp" : "string"
        "item" : [{"name":"string"}, {...} ...]
    }
}
```

When I run a query like so,

```
    lastResponse = client.prepareSearch("index")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(qb)
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

The response gives me back a list of type_name that match the query.

Is there a way to have elasticsearch return a single "item" as oppose to the entire type_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html). Using the JSON API this would be as follows:

```
{
    "fields" : ["id", "timestamp"],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "id" : "1234567" }
    }
}
```

If using the Java API, use `setFields` as follows:

```
GetResponse response = client.prepareGet(index, type, id)
       .setFields("title")
       .execute()
       .actionGet();
```

See this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/mVMABue7_ow) post for more details.

Comment: How would I do this using the java api?